# Modifying selection in the dropdown list

Tags: web-parts, sharepoint-2007

In MOSS 2007, when you edit a web part, you can set width and hight using predetermined units of measure from the drop down list.

I want to find out where do these values come from. Are they somewhere in the database? I want to be able to modify the selection to include percent (%).

Answer (score 1):

these values are stored in format of xml(webpart description file) and these are webpart instance dependent and stored in content database. as far as converting height and width from pixels to % is concerned you would have to create a custom new tool part and remove the existing one from webpart [tool part](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2008/11/29/how-to-custom-web-part-properties-toolpart.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your input. So, what you are saying is that, I can't just add or replace one of these values to percents (%) whether in db or in the xml file? it looks like these values or the entire edit pop up is not unique and from programmatic perspective it would seem that feature would be shared across the entire suite. I have searched each table in all the databases that I thought belonged to MOSS but have not found anything remotely close.

Comment: these xml files are stored in web part library and must be stored in content database the way other lists are stored searching in database would something i would not recommend. either live with what OOTB provided by SharePoint or create your own tool part